# Protractor - error when starting webdriver-manager, seleniumProcess.pid: undefined

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, webdriver-manager

I am facing a problem when starting webdriver-manager in node_modules\protractor with windows 7. the command is :

```
node webdriver-manager start
```

Then I got the following error messages:

```
seleniumProcess.pid: undefined
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:742:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1028:32)
    at child_process.js:1109:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:343:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:492:11)
    at startup (node.js:124:16)
    at node.js:807:3
```

After searching on the Internet, I cannot find any similar question like mine that the seleniumProcess.pid is undefined.

Following is the output for java -version:

```
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure you are running `webdriver-manager` from the `protractor`'s directory? Thanks.

Comment: I am running from the node_modules\protractor\bin directory.

Comment: Ok, have you executed `webdriver-manager update` before running?

Comment: PLease run it directly: webdriver-manager start instead of **node** webdriver-manager start

Comment: @alecxe Yes. I did. The output is selenium standalone is up to date.
chromedriver is up to date.

Comment: @SakshiSingla It is no windows cmd. I have to use node to run the webdriver-manager script.

Comment: You need to run webdriver-manager start the same way as you run webdriver-manager update!

Comment: @SakshiSingla yeah. I ran them in the same way. node webdriver-manager start &&  node webdriver-manager update

Comment: Which browser are you trying to launch it with? There seems to be some issue while running the spawnCommand('java', args); while trying to start the selenium server

Comment: Also make sure the installations(protractor, selenium,selenium-server-standalone- etc are compatible with your OS - 32bit/64bit).

Comment: @SakshiSingla I use Chrome.

Comment: @user1402725 I know this is very old, but did you come up with a solution? I'm getting the same error, but I'm at a loss for solutions.

Comment: Having the same problem, found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js Probably I'll go debug more.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I figured out why I had this problem. You have only JRE, but

> You will need to have the Java Development Kit (JDK) installed to run
>   the standalone Selenium Server. Check this by running java -version
>   from the command line. [Tutorial](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial)

On Ubuntu I've done

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

And now I have this Java:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_95"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.15.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

And `webdriver-manager start` works.

Answer (score 0):

Error:
C:\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriv
er-manager\bin>webdriver-manager --verbose update

events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at Error (native)
    at TLSSocket. (_tls_wrap.js:1092:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:610:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:440:38)

I did the following to remove this:

Try:
1. C:\XX\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriv
er-manager\bin>webdriver-manager --proxy http://username:passwd@IP:port
080/ update
(Then it updated drivers in the location)

2. webdriver-manager status
3. C:\XX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\bin>webdriver-manager --verbose start

It is started working, 
I expect this is happening repeatedly due to corruption of drivers. May we need to graceful stop to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `C:\Windows\System32\ there (right-click My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables -> Edit...` PATH and add `C:\Windows\System32` to the end (with a semi-colon separating each variable).